# Java - how to stop a thread running arbitrary code?

Tags: java, multithreading, jruby

In my application which runs user submitted code[1] in separate threads, there might be some cases where the code might take very long to run or it might even have an infinite loop! In that case how do I stop that particular thread?

I'm not in control of the user code, so I cannot check for Thread.interrupted() from the inside. Nor can I use Thread.stop() carelessly. I also cannot put those code in separate processes.

So, is there anyway to handle this situation?

[1] I'm using JRuby, and the user code is in ruby.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+kill+thread but no, there isn't

Comment: @sfussenegger: All of the answers suggest using Thread.interrupt() or Thread.stop() with care. _I'm just asking whether if there's any other way. There might a way._

Comment: well, at least you don't get discouraged easily by dozens of answers suggesting there isn't another way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the constraints you've provided:

1. User submitted code you have no control over.
2. Cannot force checks for `Thread.interrupted()`.
3. Cannot use `Thread.stop()`.
4. Cannot put the user code in a process jail.

The answer to your question is "no, there is no way of handling this situation".  You've pretty much systematically designed things so that you have zero control over untrusted third-party code.  This is ... a suboptimal design.

If you want to be able to handle anything, you're going to have to relax one (or preferably more!) of the above constraints.

---

*Edited to add:*

There might be a way around this for you without forcing your clients to change code if that is a(nother) constraint.  Launch the Ruby code in another process and use some form of IPC mechanism to do interaction with your main code base.  To avoid forcing the Ruby code to suddenly have to be coded to use explicit IPC, drop in a set of proxy objects for your API that do the IPC behind the scenes which themselves call proxy objects in your own server.  That way your client code is given the illusion of working inside your server while you jail that code in its own process (which you can ultimately `kill -9` as the ultimate sanction should it come to that).

Later you're going to want to wean your clients from the illusion since IPC and native calls *are* very different and hiding that behind a proxy can be evil, but it's a stopgap you can use while you deprecate APIs and move your clients over to the new APIs.

Comment: I'm able to sandbox the user code using the Security Manager, but for a simple thing like `while(true);` I have no solution.

Comment: Hence a "process jail" instead of a thread.  I'm going to post a potential alternative design in an edit here.

Comment: +1: The only good sandbox is a different process. A provided proxy-behind-the-scenes API is an elegant solution. It's the same way Google Chrome browser runs its plugins (even each one of its tabs!). If you cannot logically prove any user code is safe (by example, proving each of the building blocks is safe and its composition is safe too) you must sandbox it. A process is the only way (because even a different classloader will expose JVM class singletons and stuff like that).

Comment: @JustMYCorrectOpinion: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm already using a seperate JVM for the user code, but the thing is- all these are critical/important user code belonging to `different users`. So, I cannot spawn that many JVMs. I guess I'll think of someother way. Thanks again! ^^

Comment: You could spawn a JVM for each user if each user submits multiple code modules.

Comment: @RubyDosa You could also use one JVM for multiple inputs. For instance, use one JVM to submit jobs for 30 seconds and kill the process 15 seconds later. In the worst case, a thread is running for 45 seconds. As a result, you'd have no more than two JVMs running user code at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Ruby angle (or of the threading angle) of things here, but if you're running user-submitted code, you had best run it in a separate process rather than in a separate thread of the same process.

Rule number one: Never trust user input. Much less if the input is code!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a variable to indicate to stop a thread. Some other thread then would set this variable to true. Finally you periodically check, whether the variable is set or not.

But given that you can't change user code , **I am afraid there isn't a safe way of doing it**.

Answer (score -2):

For Running Thread `Thread.Interrupt`  wont actually stop as  sfussenegger mentioned aforth (thanks  sfussenegger recollected after reading spec).

using a shared variable to signal that it  should stop what it is doing. The thread should check the variable periodically,(ex : use a while loop ) and exit in an orderly manner.

```
private boolean isExit= false;

public void beforeExit() {
    isExit= true;
}

public void run() {
    while (!isExit) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thread.interrupt() does nothing if the code running in that thread is not under your control.

Comment: -1 calling Thread.interrupt() won't raise an InterruptedException unless the thread is in an interruptible state (blocked or waiting).